# nuxt.js Responsive navigation, small screen first click does not take effect, only after the refresh line

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In Mounted, perform DOM operations to check whether the screen size does not take effect.

```
mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.initheader();
        }, 300);
    },
methods: {
        initheader() {
            if (process.client) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
                    if (screenWidth < 991) {
                        $('.nav-item').click(e => {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            $(e.currentTarget)
                                .siblings('.nav-item')
                                .removeClass('active');
                            if (
                                e.currentTarget.classList.value.indexOf(
                                    'active'
                                ) != -1
                            ) {
                                $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
                            } else {
                                $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
                            }
                        });
                        $('.ulone li').click(e => {
                            e.stopPropagation();
                            $(e.target).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
                            if (
                                e.target.classList.value.indexOf('active') != -1
                            ) {
                                $(e.target).removeClass('active');
                            } else {
                                $(e.target).addClass('active');
                            }
                        });
                        $('.nav-item.two .ulone li a.ulone-a').click(e => {
                            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode)
                                .siblings('.nav-item')
                                .removeClass('active');
                            if (
                                e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.value.indexOf(
                                    'active'
                                ) != -1
                            ) {
                                $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).removeClass(
                                    'active'
                                );
                            } else {
                                $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).addClass(
                                    'active'
                                );
                            }
                        });
                        $('.ultwo li').click(() => {
                            $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                            this.s_yes_no = true;
                        });
                        $('.nav-item-auto .ulone li a').click(() => {
                            $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                            this.s_yes_no = true;
                        });
                        $('.nav-item.first').click(() => {
                            $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                            this.s_yes_no = true;
                        });
                    }
                });
                console.log(window.navigator.userAgent);
                if (
                    window.navigator.userAgent.match(
                        /(phone|pad|pod|iPhone|iPad|iPod|ios|Android|Mobile|BlackBerry|IEMobile|MQQBrowser|JUC|Fennec|wOSBrowser|BrowserNG|WebOS|Symbian|Windows Phone)/i
                    )
                ) {
                    $('.nav-item').click(e => {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(e.currentTarget)
                            .siblings('.nav-item')
                            .removeClass('active');
                        if (
                            e.currentTarget.classList.value.indexOf('active') !=
                            -1
                        ) {
                            $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
                        } else {
                            $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                    $('.ulone li').click(e => {
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        $(e.target).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
                        if (e.target.classList.value.indexOf('active') != -1) {
                            $(e.target).removeClass('active');
                        } else {
                            $(e.target).addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                    $('.nav-item.two .ulone li a.ulone-a').click(e => {
                        $(e.currentTarget.parentNode)
                            .siblings('.nav-item')
                            .removeClass('active');
                        if (
                            e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.value.indexOf(
                                'active'
                            ) != -1
                        ) {
                            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).removeClass('active');
                        } else {
                            $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                    $('.ultwo li').click(() => {
                        $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                        this.s_yes_no = true;
                    });
                    $('.nav-item-auto .ulone li a').click(() => {
                        $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                        this.s_yes_no = true;
                    });
                    $('.nav-item.first').click(() => {
                        $('.navbar-toggler').click();
                        this.s_yes_no = true;
                    });
                }
            }
            // if (document.body.clientWidth < 991) {
            //     $('.nav-item').click(e => {
            //         e.stopPropagation();
            //         $(e.currentTarget)
            //             .siblings('.nav-item')
            //             .removeClass('active');
            //         if (
            //             e.currentTarget.classList.value.indexOf('active') != -1
            //         ) {
            //             $(e.currentTarget).removeClass('active');
            //         } else {
            //             $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
            //         }
            //     });
            //     $('.ulone li').click(e => {
            //         e.stopPropagation();
            //         $(e.target).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
            //         if (e.target.classList.value.indexOf('active') != -1) {
            //             $(e.target).removeClass('active');
            //         } else {
            //             $(e.target).addClass('active');
            //         }
            //     });
            //     $('.nav-item.two .ulone li a.ulone-a').click(e => {
            //         $(e.currentTarget.parentNode)
            //             .siblings('.nav-item')
            //             .removeClass('active');
            //         if (
            //             e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.value.indexOf(
            //                 'active'
            //             ) != -1
            //         ) {
            //             $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).removeClass('active');
            //         } else {
            //             $(e.currentTarget.parentNode).addClass('active');
            //         }
            //     });
            //     $('.ultwo li').click(() => {
            //         $('.navbar-toggler').click();
            //         this.s_yes_no = true;
            //     });
            //     $('.nav-item-auto .ulone li a').click(() => {
            //         $('.navbar-toggler').click();
            //         this.s_yes_no = true;
            //     });
            //     $('.nav-item.first').click(() => {
            //         $('.navbar-toggler').click();
            //         this.s_yes_no = true;
            //     });
            // }
        },
},
```

These methods, whether the comments or no comments, for the first time can't get to the current screen width, only after refresh the line, so the navigation also can only be set to come into force after, before I see a solution, it need to put the script in the body, but  When I  used in nuxt.js, how should do

Comment: jQuery and vue.js? (don't use jq in vue project

Comment: @Xiao_e_yun I've explained OP that this issue should be solved in CSS.